# Partition $\mathbb{N}_0$ into two sets where each set must have the same number of ways to add to m

Tags: contest-math, set-partition

For any set that is a subset of the natural numbers $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}_0$ we may consider the number of possible ways to form $m$ by adding two distinct elements in $S$. Call this $c_S(m)$. For example, if $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ there are 2 ways to form $6$ : $1 + 5$ and $2 + 4$. So $c_S(6) = 2$.

Is there a way to partition $\mathbb{N}_0$ into two sets $A$, $B$ such that $c_A(m) = c_B(m)$ for all $m$?

I played around with this and tried splitting the sets into the evens and the odds and it seems to work for any number that is not of the form $4k+2$, so I'm beginning to think that it's not possible but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: The generating function for $c_S$ is $\prod_{n\in S}(1+x^n).$ But not sure if that helps.

Comment: Your conjectured split would imply $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N_0}(1+x^n)$ is the square of an integer power series which seems unlikely. But I think the coefficient of $x^1$ is $1,$ so that can't be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambek and Moser in "[On some two way classifications of integers](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/on-some-two-way-classifications-of-integers/C36087ADE965C59BE843D73B9FA11A87)" proved that there is exactly one such partition: into evil and odious numbers (numbers that have even and odd 1s in binary respectively). It uses generating function, as Thomas suggested in comments.

(the way I found this paper is generating few elements of each set - it's easy to do by hand, as if we put $0$ to $A$, we have to put $1$ and $2$ in $B$, then $3$ in $A$ and so on, and checked if OEIS contains corresponding sequence (it does, and also contains statement from the question and a link to the paper above))